# How do you change the add button text instead of a

Tags: objective-c, xcode

The add button that comes as the default for the MasterDetail template in XCode displays a + symbol.  I would rather have the word "Add" instead.  I tried using the following line in the viewDidLoad method:

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.title = @"Add";

to no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably because the bar button that has already been created as `UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd` like so:

```
UIBarButtonItem *addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(insertNewObject:)];
```

You should rewrite this line to create a bar button item with a title, like this:

```
UIBarButtonItem *addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Add" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(insertNewObject:)];
```

You can find this in the `viewDidLoad` method of your master view controller.